# Google VM recovery

Tags: google-compute-engine

I need help recovering from a really boneheaded mistake with my Google VM.

I inadvertently removed NetworkManager from the VM and am hoping someone knows how to recover from this the Google cloudshell.

The OS is Rocky 8.4.

Comment: I have not tried to recover from that problem. Try using the Google Cloud serial console to connect to the VM. Then reenable Network Manager. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-using-serial-console

Answer (score 1):

OK, I finally recalled that I could connect to the serial console and log in.  Then it was a matter of [configuring eth0 with the assigned address](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/create-use-multiple-interfaces#creating_virtual_machine_instances_with_multiple_network_interfaces), adding a default route, then re-installing NetworkManager and I was  back in business after a reboot.